# PATH different in VSCode (due to conda)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, system-variable

I am trying to get my VSCode terminal to see a mingw installation.
When I run the command...

```
gcc --version
```

... in regular CMD, it works as expected.

However, when I use it in VSCode terminal, it isn't found.

Upon checking, the PATH variables are slightly different across both terminals (CMD and VSCode).

I do have conda installed, and when I open the terminal in VSCode, it defaults to it. Doesn't matter if I `conda deactivate` however; still have the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say `CMD` so I'm assuming you are using Windows. What is your "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" entry in your `setting.json` file? Are you indeed using CMD or some PowerShell in the integrated terminal on VS Code?

Comment: Also, if you just added `gcc` to environment path, you need to close and re-open VS Code so that the path is available in integrated terminal (Only needed to be done once after Path is added). So do close and re-open VS code after the path is added if not done already